# Python Equivalent to SQL Rank

Tags: python, pandas, dense-rank

I want to have an SQL rank equivalent in python pandas module. I want to filter out all the dates which have the rank = 1

I've the following dataframe:

```
id    date
12    2021-06-01
12    2021-06-15
12    2021-06-21
34    2021-06-05
87    2021-06-19
53    2021-06-05
```

and I need to apply rank in the following way:

```
id    date          rank
12    2021-06-01      1
12    2021-06-15      2
12    2021-06-21      3
34    2021-06-05      1
87    2021-06-19      1
53    2021-06-05      1
```

The SQL for this would be

```
select id, date, rank() over (partition by id order by date asc) as rank 
from table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['rank'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
   id       date  rank
0  12 2021-06-01     1
1  12 2021-06-15     2
2  12 2021-06-21     3
3  34 2021-06-05     1
4  87 2021-06-19     1
5  53 2021-06-05     1
```

If datetimes are sorted per groups is possible [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['id','date'])
df['rank'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].cumcount().add(1)
```

Comment: This is the error: "pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"

Comment: @Prudhavi - Can you add `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` before my solution?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. And also I didn't know we could change the entire column to date using pd.to_dateframe. Useful tip.